# How to Get the Value From Web Span Element in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, element

Here is the element obtained by inspect:

```
<span class="sstats" id="connected_modems">36</span>
```

I am trying to get the value `36` out of this element in Python.

When I try to print out the value `36` by following Python code,

```py
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("connected_modems")
    for attr in element.get_property('attributes'):
          print(attr['name'],attr['value'])
    print("element value:", element.text)
```

I only get

```
   class sstats
   id connected_modems
   element value: 0
```

When I try to find the value by view source of the webpage, the value is `0` instead of `36`, as following,

```
    <span class="sstats" id="connected_modems">0</span>
```

How can I get the value `36` out of this element?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `element.get_attribute("innerHTML")`

Comment: I got 0 with element.get_attribute("innerHTML")

Comment: @AlWays Is that value generated by Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get the element text by simply this:

```py
element_text = driver.find_element(By.ID, "connected_modems").text
```

Comment: I got 0 with this code

Comment: There are several possible options why you got this result. We need to see the link to the page you working on and all your existing code

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these 3 attributes to get the text.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("connected_modems")

element_value = element.textContent
OR
element_value = element.innerHTML
OR
element_value = element.innerText
```

[This](https://builtin.com/software-engineering-perspectives/innerhtml-vs-innertext) is a pretty good article about the differences between those three attributes to keep in mind.

Comment: all 3 code crashed